# Cannot download images from remote server using SDWebImageManager on iOS

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

Want to achieve image gallery through UICollectionView. I have a set of image url's in an array, say around 20-30 url's. Using SDWebImageManager to download images and cache it and display on the collection view.

See my code below:

```
for(int i=0;i<[imagePath count];i++) {

    [manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[imagePath objectAtIndex:i]] options:0 progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize) {

    } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {

        if(image){
            NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
            NSString *localKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item-%d", i];
            NSLog(@"%@",localKey);
            [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:image forKey:localKey];
        }

    }];
}
```

All it does is, display the first image that has the url link indexed 0 in my imagePath array and the rest of the cell's remain blank. When tried to print it just displays SUCCESS once and Item-0. I guess its not going any further. It downloads just one image(first url's image in the array). Please help me with this. I am breaking my head on this from a long time. Not sure if i am on right track. Or please do suggest me other alternatives of achieving image gallery through multiple url's stored in an array.

Comment: Use the `UIImageView+WebCache` image view category instead, that will do the caching of images as well. Usage can be [found here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#using-uiimageviewwebcache-category-with-uitableview)

Comment: Thanks for the reply amar. yeah i used UIImageView+WebCache but its not working. It just loads one image.

Answer (score 0):

I have to wonder what your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is doing. If it's trying to retrieve the images from the cache directly, you might see precisely the behavior you describe (where the above code is running asynchronously and thus the images are not yet downloaded by the time `cellForItemAtIndexPath` tries to retrieve them from the cache).

Personally, I'd suggest that you do not even bother trying to populate your cache in advance. Just have `cellForItemAtIndexPath` just use the `UIImageView+WebCache` category method `setImageWithURL` and remove the `for` loop in your question altogether. It will automatically fill the cache for you and the problem of missing images will probably go away.

If you're having troubles retrieving your images, you should use one of the SDWebImage methods that passes a `NSError` object back to the block. For example:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%s: setImageWithURL error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
}];
```

If the URL address is not valid, you may see a 404 error.

---

If you're determined to use your `for` loop, a couple of other thoughts:

1. BTW, you are logging only if `image` is non-`nil`. You might want an `else` statement for your `if` statement fails (e.g. perhaps the `error` object can tell you something interesting). If an API provides an `error` object, you should avail yourself of it.
2. It's a little curious that are taking a downloaded image and adding it to the cache with another key; now you have two copies of the image in your cache, which is a wasteful use of space. Once you've downloaded an image, it's already in the cache, and if you try to retrieve the image again using the same URL, it will pull it from the cache. There's no point in creating another entry in the cache with your own key.
3. If you're not going to use the `progress` block, you can just pass `nil` for that parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rob. I did try UIImageView+WebCache. Its of no help. It still shows one image i.e from the first url of the array. May be its taking time to download all the 20-30 images. All url's are different. Its not the same url path.

Comment: @Uday If you're having troubles returning images both ways, then the issue is likely in your URLs. For example, Mac OS X isn't case sensitive, but many web servers are, so perhaps the case doesn't match. I can't say without seeing the URLs. But if you use a rendition with a `completed` block, you can better diagnose what the source of the problem is. See my revised answer.

Comment: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1100.)"

Comment: @Uday That translates to `kCFURLErrorFileDoesNotExist`, I believe. See [CFNetwork Error Codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: You have been of great help to me. Thanks you so much your direction. I tried with few sample links from Google. it loads up images fine. As you said,the problem with URL's. But when i try the my own URL's on the browser it shows me the images.

Comment: @Uday Are there any characters outside of the [0-9] and [a-z] and [A-Z] ranges. For example, any spaces or other characters? Often web browsers invisibly do the necessary percent escaping of the characters when you type the URL in the browser. If so, you can use [stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:).

Comment: Bulls Eye :) @Rob you made my day. It was the space in url causing problem. I removed it. And it works great. Thanks for baring with me buddy :)